# NLopt / nloptr Settings and Output

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nlopt

I have two questions regarding [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and one regarding `nloptr`, which is an R interface to NLopt. In terms of the specific method, I am aiming for a gradient based method such as "BFGS".

NLopt:

1. How do you choose the termination criterion? In particular, how do you
   decide if you focus on xtol, ftol or both and how would you then decide on a specific value / values for your choice.
2. What does the NLopt status "NLOPT_SUCCESS = 1 (Generic success return value.)" mean? How can there be a successful termination if neither xtol nor ftol is reached?

`nloptr`:

1. How can you change the number M of gradients to "remember" from previous optimization steps for "L-BFGS"? I can't find the "nlopt_set_vector_storage", which is used in the original `C`code.

Comment: Typically neither xtol nor ftol are used, but either gtol (popular in first-order opt; not sure if available in NLopt) or even second-order information. If possible, something based on KKT-conditions. This of course depends on the solver and it's assumptions (there is more than one solver)!

Comment: I solve nonlinear optimization problems every day, and I basically never tinker with optimality tolerances. If you have convergence problems it is much better to look at bounds, scaling and initial points.

Comment: Thanks @sascha - unfortunately there isn't any option in `nloptr` for a gtol convergence criterion. Is there any other package you can recommend / you usually use ?

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen - I tried with bounds and scaling, yet no difference. In case of initial points, the problem is highly sensitive to those. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Actual questions, will be happy to find the answers.

Comment: Can you give more information on the problem you're trying to solve? The answer to question 1 depends very much on the problem. If for example you are minimizing a negative log likelihood you generally only care about the result to within 1 standard deviation which means setting an ftol of ~0.5.